# Problema para cambiar valores en un columna en dataFrame en R

Tags: r

Voy a empezar desde el inicio tengo una función que realiza lo siguiente 
obtiene un string y me devuelve un parte del string

```
x <- "LABEL=UCI-1, CellIndex=50, CGI=368010016000"
```

y mi funcion :

```
value <-substr(x,7,stop=gregexpr(',',x)[[1]][1]-1)
```

retorna `"UCI-1"`,  de igual manera con un string `"LABEL=MARRIBA-1, CellIndex=50, CGI=368010016000"` la función devuelve `"MARRIBA-1"`

En si lo que hace es coger lo que esta después del signo "=" y lo anterior a la primera ",". Hasta ahí todo bien, pero cuando tengo un `dataFrame` como lo pongo por si desean probarlo

```
emp.data <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c (1:3), 
  emp_name = c("LABEL=UCI-1, CellIndex=50, CGI=368010016000","LABEL=UCI-3, CellIndex=34, CGI=3680100150014","LABEL=MARRIB2, CellIndex=50, CGI=368010016000"),
  salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

y ejecuto la función

```
emp.data$emp_name<-substr(emp.data$emp_name,7,stop=gregexpr(',',emp.data$emp_name)[[1]][1]-1)
```

los valores que me devuelve con la función que cree en la columna emp_name son :

```
UCI-1 ---
UCI-2 ---
MARRI // el cual es incorrecto ya que deberia ser MARRIBA2
```

Entiendo que mi problema es que la función adopta los indices de la "," a partir de su primera ejecución y no entiendo por que lo hace si recorre cada fila del `dataFrame` por separado. Lo que quiero es ayuda para lograr que el resultado de mi columna `emp_name` en mi  `dataFrame` sea:

```
UCI-1 ---
UCI-2 --- 
MARRIBA2 ---
```

PD: tengo muchos mas datos no limiten las respuestas a solo estas tres columnas 
EJ : `HLSBO2` u otros mas

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es este:

```
> gregexpr(',',emp.data$emp_name)[[1]][1]-1
[1] 11
```

Estas usando esto para determinar hasta dónde "recortar" cada valor de `emp.data$emp_name`, `gregexpr()` te retorna una lista con las posiciones de cada coma, (ninguna, una o varias) de cada uno de los valores de `emp_name`, sin embargo, puedes ver que el retorno final es un único valor, el problema es el acceso por índices que intentas, de ninguna forma funciona como lo has planteado. Creo que la forma más sencilla, es hacer esto:

```
> unlist(lapply(gregexpr(',',emp.data$emp_name), `[[`, 1))-1
[1] 11 11 13
```

Conceptualmente lo que estamos haciendo con `lapply` es lo siguiente:

```
c(gregexpr(',',emp.data$emp_name)[[1]][1] - 1,
  gregexpr(',',emp.data$emp_name)[[2]][1] - 1,
  gregexpr(',',emp.data$emp_name)[[3]][1] - 1)
```

Es decir, obtenemos el primer elemento de cada vector de la lista y con `unlist` dejamos listo el resultado de forma más "plana".

Finalmente, quedaría todo así:

```
> substr(emp.data$emp_name,7,stop=unlist(lapply(gregexpr(',',emp.data$emp_name), `[[`, 1))-1)
[1] "UCI-1"   "UCI-3"   "MARRIB2"
```

Comment: Muy acertada tu respuesta era lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias